# jQuery countdown/count up with server-side values

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

Script: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.htm

Daily json response:

```
items: { fajr: '5:23 am', sharooq: '7:23 am', dhur: '1:34 pm', asr: '4:66 pm': magrib: '6:23 pm', isha: '8:01 pm'}
```

When the site loads, I make an Ajax request and get the above response times. These are events that happen daily, with different timings. I want to get that time and put a count down on how many minutes are left or hours or seconds, and show that and once the seconds are done, then show how many minutes ago that event took place. After 15 minutes, show a new event count down. This is how it will look on the display:

```
dhur 2 hours left
dhur 2 minutes left (if no longer hours left)
dhur 55 seconds left (if no longer minutes left)
dhur 5 seconds ago (if count down finished and then show how many seconds ago)
dhur 9 minutes ago (if extended more then seconds, then show how many minutes ago)
asr 1 hour left (after 15 minutes later time changes to new event)
```

If the script I'm using is not good and you prefer some other script for this kind of task, please share with me. It doesn't have to be a jQuery script, but it helps if it's jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you would be better off not reimplementing this thing.

There is already a really nice jQuery plugin for this functionality (with i18n support too)

[jQuery timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

> Timeago is a jQuery plugin that makes
>   it easy to support automatically
>   updating fuzzy timestamps
>   (e.g. "4 minutes ago" or "about 1 day
>   ago" or "2 years from now")

P.S.: don't forget to set `jQuery.timeago.settings.allowFuture = true;` to allow dates in the future

---

If you need some sort of "callback" you could do two things.

1. Assuming you only supported english (no i18n) simply use `setInterval` which every 20-25 seconds checks if the string set by jQuery timeago is "15 minutes ago" and then do whatever
2. <strike>Hack</strike> Adapt the code of the plugin and hook yourself into the e.g. `$timeago.inWords` method and do whatever if the `distanceMillis` parameter is `>=900000` (15*60*1000).

Comment: it dosn't support callback, how can i get around that? like callback on every sec or when its changing.. cause i have to run action after count down is done.